# Why was my question 'Drop Dead Dragon' closed?

Tags: discussion, closing

I'm not sure why a question was closed and couldn't find a better place to discuss it:

[Drop Dead Dragon](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/102216/drop-dead-dragon)

It was closed as an exact duplicate of two questions. Both of which talk about the same bug each, where a dead dragon body either appears suddenly in an area or falls from the sky. My question was about why a dragon that dropped dead in the middle of a fight, while attacking, flying and roaring, it wasn't an animation bug and it didn't just die suddenly and fall lifeless from the sky. I explained this in the comments and in a small update but perhaps this was just missed by reviewers.

If not I'm genuinely not sure why it should be closed, there's not a satisfactory answer in either of the supposed duplicates.

Comment: Well this is the place to ask - I didn't take part in the closing of your question but if indeed the two suggested duplicates are in fact not a duplicate of your question then it shouldn't have been closed for this reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree. Your question isn't a duplicate, and therefore I have voted to re-open.

Comment: Agreed. Voted to reopen.

Comment: Question is back open so it seems this ones solved.